# App installation failed on iPhone 6 device in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, iphone-6

[image: app installation failed]

I have all of the provisional profiles ready on the devices and it's added to the developer portal.However when I tried to run the app from xcode 6 into my new iphone 6 with iOS 8 on it, it throws me this error.

any ideas how to fix it? all of my provisioning profiles are valid and active. the code signing identity is correct.

when  i tried to run on another ipad with iOS 8, it throws me this error:

[image]

Comment: I think your image failed to upload

Comment: I had the same error. Did you add your device to the provisioning profile?

Comment: @SleepParalysis can you see it now?

Comment: @beeefyes, when i connect the phone and it seems to load all of the profiles

Comment: Go to developers.apple.com, Member Center -> iOS. There you can have a look at all your provisioning profiles etc.
Open the provisioning profile you are using for this app. Is your iPhone 6 included in this provisioning profile?

Comment: @beeef  yes, the device is included in the device list. and the app store & ad hoc provisional profiles are generated to include them

Answer (score 3):

[image]

seems like setting provisional profile as automatic will do the trick instead of the app store or Ad hoc profile

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download your provisioning profile from the dev centre and install it by using keychain. After doing so it should work.

Comment: I already had one installed, do i have to delete the old ones and download them again?

Comment: Most likely, but make sure that the they are still valid in the dev centre.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your developer certification, try to change the provision to solve it

Comment: as my develope experience ,your wrong is associate to developer provisioning,you goto apple deleloper center  renew a developer provision ,try to solve your problem. good luck